# Get Deleted Text

Tags: android, text, android-edittext

I am using `onTextChanged(charSequence s, int start, int before, int count)` and would like to get the deleted text of an Edittext. I believe you can get it through the parameter s but how would I know that the text has been deleted not added? (E.g. `if s.equals("Example")` how do I know that "Example" was deleted from, not added to, the Edittext?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're deleting text from an EditText, the final parameter for `onTextChanged`, `int lengthAfter` should be equal to zero (you have this parameter labeled 'count').

[`onTextChanged (CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

You could also consider using a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for finer control.

Answer (score -1):

Use onTextChanged or TextWatcher that doesn't matter, to get text from these methods and recognize whether it was deleted or added, you've to write your own code of logic as follows.

- Get text from onTextChanged method on String 1
- Get text from EditText on String 2
- Convert the string to array of characters.
- Loop through,compare & find missing characters.

I said this unique Algorithm for your problem which had not been asked.